# Force users to comment after they edit a question

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, etiquette

A lot of times as I read through questions, I see that someone else has edited it.

This being a pseudo-wiki, maybe the system should "force" a user to comment on why said question was edited?

I don't like the idea of *forcing*, but I also would like to see why the main part of the question was edited.

Comment: But if you keep boiling it, you ruin all the taste.

Comment: no. this is a bad idea - besides, the edit history contains all, well, historical entries of edits

Comment: What benefit would this have given that edits need to have a description, which gets displayed in the (public) revision list?

Answer (score 20):

> Asdfasdfasdfasdf.

Is that ok? Forcing people to write an explanation for their action usually backfires. The system, as it is now, is more than ok. If it really needs explaining, a lot of people will voluntarily fill in the **edit summary** field.

Comment: I usually fill in the edit summary if I'm editing other people's posts, but sometimes not if it's really obvious (like correcting a typo).

Comment: Usually I enter a typo when filling in the edit summary, only to notice it as I click the submit button. :-(